# Scp with @ and : in username

Tags: bash, ssh, scp

I would like to know how can i use SCP with username like that :

```
coucou@kiki:SSH:myname
```

I'm trying with something like that:

```
scp "coucou@kiki:SSH:myname@11.1.1:/var/log/apache /var/log1"
```

but I get the following error :

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname kiki: Name or service not known
```

Comment: You could use `scp -o "User=coucou@kiki:SSH:myname" 11.1.1:/var/log/apache /var/log1` at worst, but try escaping the `@` with a backslash first

Comment: Perhaps it's not the best username at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that escaping the `@` in the username using SSH worked, but SCP did not.

You can pass the underlying SSH options directly with the `-o` option with SCP. For example:

```
scp -o "User=coucou@kiki:SSH:myname" 11.1.1:/var/log/apache /var/log1
```